# Reference for connection of a Hessian metric

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $f: M \to \Bbb R$ be a smooth function. One can consider the covariant Hessian $\nabla ({\rm d}f)$. Some time ago I had seen a paper, which regrettably I do not recall the name, studying the pseudo-Riemannian geometry of $M$ equipped with $\nabla({\rm d}f)$ (when said Hessian is non-degenerate). In particular, the author(s) obtain an (coordinate-free) expression for the Levi-Civita connection of the Hessian metric in terms of the connection of the original metric.

The [Pacific Journal of Mathematics](https://msp.org/pjm/2018/295-2/) and the [Balkan Journal of Geometry 
and Its Applications](http://www.mathem.pub.ro/bjga/) both come to mind, but looking through these websites I did not found anything.

Maybe someone here happens to know the reference off the top of their head. If this question seems off-topic, I'll just delete it. Thanks!